# Java2d: Translate the axes

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I am developing an application using Java2d. The weird thing I noticed is, the origin is at the top left corner and positive x goes right and positive y increases down.

Is there a way to move the origin bottom left?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the standard axis layout for most gui systems, it comes from back when everything was text based so upper left made sense as the origin for text.  Most GUI toolkits will let you flip the origin and axis around but my advice is to just get used to it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to need to do a Scale and a translate.

in your `paintComponent` method you could do this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(0, -height);
    g2d.scale(1.0, -1.0);
    //draw your component with the new coordinates

    //you may want to reset the transforms at the end to prevent
    //other controls from making incorrect assumptions
    g2d.scale(1.0, -1.0);
    g2d.translate(0, height);
}
```

my Swing is a little rusty but this should accomplish the task.

Comment: I do not like how you set the scale/translate back. It *should* be okay in this particular special case, but in general you would accumulate floating point errors as you stack the transforms. Better to call getTransform and then setTransform to restore the original.

Comment: That's odd I had to swap the order of `translate` and `scale` calls to get that code to actually work...

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following way to resolve easily the problem,

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
// Flip the sign of the coordinate system
g2d.translate(0.0, getHeight());
g2d.scale(1.0, -1.0);
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Graphics2D.translate()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate(int,%20int))?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to just get used to it.  Like luke mentioned, you technically CAN apply a transform to the graphics instance, but that will end up affecting performance negatively.

Just doing a translate could move the position of 0,0 to the bottom left, but movement along the positive axes will still be right in the x direction and down in the y direction, so the only thing you would accomplish is drawing everything offscreen.  You'd need to do a rotate to accomplish what you're asking, which would add the overhead of radian calculations to the transform matrix of the graphics instance.  That is not a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Just for later reference, I had to swap the order of the calls to `scale` and `translate` in my code. Maybe this will help someone in the future:

```
@Test
public void bottomLeftOriginTest() throws IOException {
    int width = 256;
    int height = 512;

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);    
    Graphics2D ig = bi.createGraphics();
    // save the "old" transform
    AffineTransform old = ig.getTransform();

    // origin is top left:
    // update graphics object with the inverted y-transform
    if (true) { /* order ok */
        ig.scale(1.0, -1.0);
        ig.translate(0, -bi.getHeight());
    } else {
        ig.translate(0, -bi.getHeight());
        ig.scale(1.0, -1.0);
    }

    int xPoints[] = new int[] { 0, width, width };
    int yPoints[] = new int[] { 0, height, 0 };
    int nPoints = xPoints.length;
    ig.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    ig.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

    ig.setColor(Color.RED);
    ig.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);

    // restore the old transform
    ig.setTransform(old);

    // Export the result to a file
    ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("origin.png"));
}
```

[image: bottom left origin]